# All combinations for matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, combinations

I'm trying find all combinations of an n-by-n matrix without repetitions.

For example, I have a matrix like this:

```
A = [321 319 322; ...
     320 180 130; ...
     299 100 310];
```

I want the following result:

> (321 180 310)
>   (321 130 100)
>   (319 320 310)
>   (319 139 299)
>   (322 320 100)
>   (322 180 299)

I have tried using `ndgrid`, but it takes the row or the column twice.

Comment: Please include some code to show
[what you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler (native) solution with [`perms`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html) and [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html):

```
N = size(A, 1);
X = perms(1:N);                    % # Permuations of column indices
Y = meshgrid(1:N, 1:factorial(N)); % # Row indices
idx = (X - 1) * N + Y;             % # Convert to linear indexing
C = A(idx)                         % # Extract combinations
```

The result is a matrix, each row containing a different combination of elements:

```
C =

   321   180   310
   319   320   310
   321   130   100
   319   130   299
   322   320   100
   322   180   299
```

This solution can also be shortened to:

```
C = A((perms(1:N) - 1) * N + meshgrid(1:N, 1:factorial(N)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`ALLCOMB` is the key to your question

E.g. I am not front of a MATLAB machine so, I took a sample from web.

```
x = allcomb([1 3 5],[-3 8],[],[0 1]) ;
ans
1 -3 0
1 -3 1
1 8 0
...
5 -3 1
5 8 0
5 8 1
```

Comment: if you enter the arguments to `allcomb` as rows of given matrix, it  will lead to repeated columns, which is not what is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `perms` to permute the columns as follows:

```
% A is given m x n matrix
row = 1:size( A, 1 );
col = perms( 1:size( A, 2 ) );

B = zeros( size( col, 1 ), length( row )); % Allocate memory for storage

% Simple for-loop (this should be vectorized)
% for c = 1:size( B, 2 )
%     for r = 1:size( B, 1 )
%         B( r, c ) = A( row( c ), col( r, c ));
%     end
% end

% Simple for-loop (further vectorization possible)
r = 1:size( B, 1 );
for c = 1:size( B, 2 )
    B( r, c ) = A( row( c ), col( r, c ));
end
```